# Is playing an illegal Wild Draw 4 considered cheating or a bluff?

Tags: uno, cheating

From the official [2001 Uno rules](https://service.mattel.com/instruction_sheets/42001pr.pdf) (emphasis in original),

> **Wild Draw 4 card**... You can only play this card when you don't have a card in your hand that matches the color of the card previously played.... If you suspect that a player has played a Wild Draw 4 card illegally, you may challenge them. A challenged player must show his/her hand.... If the challenged player is guilty, he/she must draw the 4 cards. If the challenged player is not guilty, the challenger must draw the 4 cards, plus 2 additional cards. Only the person required to draw the 4 cards can make the challenge.

I was playing a game of Uno recently where this came up in my mind. I had a Wild Draw 4 in my hand and strongly believed that my opponent was likely to go out if I did not play it right then, even though I did have a matching color card in my hand. I decided to bluff and play the Wild Draw 4. My opponent did not challenge, and I went on to win the trick.

In retrospect, I've had a nagging feeling that what I did was not bluffing, but outright cheating. I'm not sure if my behavior was more akin to playing non-words in Scrabble (legitimate bluffing) or moving my opponent's chess pieces while they are in the restroom (cheating). The mention of a specific in-game challenge process and in-game penalty leads me to believe that my behavior falls under bluffing rather than cheating, but the wording of the rule ("You can only..." and "illegally") seems to imply that the rule writers attach some level of morality to the rule.

*Is playing an "illegal" Wild Draw 4 considered a legitimate form of bluffing or an act of cheating?* For example, if I was caught doing this at a tournament, would my entire penalty be drawing four cards or would I also face the possibility of formal censure or tournament expulsion for willful cheating?

By analogy, I could compare this with law, where there is generally a distinction between civil wrongs (in which the offender's entire penalty is compensating whomever they hurt) and crimes (in which the offender often faces so-called "collateral" consequences for months, years, or life as as result of having a criminal "record"). So, in terms of Uno, is an illegal Wild Draw 4 player treated more like "You played that card illegally, so you have to draw four cards. Carry on then." or more like "You played that card illegally! Draw four cards! Also, you're a cheater and are banned from further Uno tournaments at this location for the next year! Your behavior will be reported to the Disciplinary Committee of the Regional Council of Uno Tournament Organizers for a possible lifetime ban! Get off my property!"?

To be clear, I am asking for the closest I can get to a "rules as written" or "rules lawyer" answer. I recognize that one can house-rule this to their heart's content.

If a more recent ruleset clarifies this situation, quoting it is a legitimate answer.

Comment: Note that there are many different beliefs about what the rules actually say. Even if something may strictly speaking be a bluff, if people aren't aware of the nuance of the rules or the possibility of challenging it, they may consider it to simply be an invalid play. In that context, taking advantage of that caveat would be poor sportsmanship.

Comment: there are no tricks in Uno.

Comment: that rule is poorly written, in that it both says you can't do X and then goes on to describe what happens if you do do X. That should be enough to determine that the only possible solution is to agree on the matter specifically before playing.

Comment: @ilkkachu that's exactly my reason for asking. It's unclear if they are *really* saying "it's ok to bluff, but you have to draw cards if you get caught" or "this is really cheating, but we have a neat way for you to enforce this rule it if you think constant hand policing with a summary beating for all offenders is too harsh".

Comment: @RobertColumbia, well, yeah, it is unclear. But my point is that it's not just unclear, it's outright self-contradictory. Other than finding the author and asking them (I would guess that unlikely for a game like Uno), or just deciding to toss the rules and decide for yourself, I don't think it can be resolved.

Comment: *"akin to playing non-words in Scrabble (legitimate bluffing)"* It is exactly akin to playing non-words in scrabble, in the sense that they're both things that you can do if your opponents agree that you can do them, but that would be terrible sportsmanship and in fact amoral if you do it against opponents who trust you not to do it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This should fall under the category of bluffing for one simple reason that is even in the quoted block of yours:

> Only the person required to draw the 4 cards can make the challenge.

If this would fall under cheating, any player at the table should be able to point it out.
Furthermore, most games don't have rules in place about what happens when you cheat/ suspect of cheating (adding extra cards on the draw or having a different player draw cards), it is usually handled by forfeiting/ losing the game.

This is the same as your bluffing example from Scrabble.

This is supported [here](https://www.maxiaids.com/Media/Uploaded/26787.pdf):

> A player holding a Wild Draw Four may choose to bluff and play the card illegally, but if he/she is caught certain rules apply (See PENALTIES)

Comment: Normally, if it is a cheat, the game ends and there is disqualification, not simply draw extra cards.

Comment: Uno is played differently by a lot of people. I never heard of this rule before. So if this rule exists and you play with it make sure everybody at the table knows the rule.

Comment: Uno is a lot like Monopolo in that regard. Too many house rules that are accepted as common/ official rules, missed and/ or unknown rules. @Nelson that is what I wrote. The (added cards) are the handling of cheating in rules, the part afterwards talks about game end and loosing it.

Comment: @Nelson: Bridge has quite a few defined penalties for cheats. That doesn't make them not cheats and abuse will eventually get players tournament banned.

Comment: @Zibelas: In the case of UNO, different publications have different rule books.

Comment: @J_rite That is a standard rule in every edition of Uno I've ever seen

Comment: @Joshua: Indeed, the American Contract Bridge League rules *explicitly* forbid deliberate infractions *even when one would be willing to pay the prescribed penalty*.

Comment: In particular, the rules have a penalty if you are incorrect in calling out the player. You risk having to draw 2 more cards if the player did play the card legally. If it was considered cheating, it wouldn't make sense to punish someone for trying to stop said cheating.

Comment: The part that make it seem weird to me is that the rules mention that bluffing is illegal, but what is the difference between cheating and engaging in illegal behavior?  Worse, it would seem to me that doing something illegal is *worse* than cheating, because not all cheating is necessarily considered illegal.

Answer (score 7):

If the game itself, not just official tournaments and such, has rules for what happens when you're caught doing it, then it's part of the game and is not cheating.

Penalties for actual cheating are external to the game itself, are typically harsh in order to motivate players to not risk even a small chance of getting caught, and are handled by whatever external entity cares about whether you cheated.

Comment: I don't think I agree with this in its entirety, though it's certainly *a* clue.  This depends so much on other things, including the culture of the group playing - if I bluffed words in Scrabble playing with my nine year old, I'd be cheating, because it's just not reasonable for him to contest every word he doesn't know.  "Cheating" is more of a moral statement than a technical one.

Comment: @Joe I would count that as part of the external factors I alluded to. Adjusting house rules to be more appropriate for a specific group of players is outside the scope of the game itself.